# Add new field in body exception spring rest

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, exception

I want to handle exceptions in my Rest spring boot application. I know that with @ControllerAdvice and ResponseEntity I can return a custom object that will represent my error, but what I want is to add a new field to the body of the exesting exception that's all.

I created a custom Exception that inherit RuntimeException with an extra attribute, a list of string :

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CONFLICT)
public class CustomException extends RuntimeException {

    private List<String> errors = new ArrayList<>();

    public CustomException(List<String> errors) {
        this.errors = errors;
    }

    public CustomException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }

    public CustomException(String message, List<String> errors) {
        super(message);
        this.errors = errors;
    }

    public List<String> getErrors() {
        return errors;
    }

    public void setErrors(List<String> errors) {
        this.errors = errors;
    }
}
```

In my controller I just throw this custom exception this way:

```
@GetMapping("/appointment")
public List<Appointment> getAppointments() {
    List<String> errors = new ArrayList<>();
    errors.add("Custom message");
    throw new CustomException("This is my message", errors);
}
```

When I test my Rest endpoint with postman, it seems like that spring boot doesn't marshall my errors field, the response is :

```
{
  "timestamp": "2017-06-05T18:19:03",
  "status": 409,
  "error": "Conflict",
  "exception": "com.htech.bimaristan.utils.CustomException",
  "message": "This is my message",
  "path": "/api/agenda/appointment"
}
```

I can go for a custom object with @ControllerAdvice if I can get the "path" and "timestamp" fields from the exception but there's no getters for these two attributes.

Thank you.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Well! Here is the implementation of "path" and "timestamp" in DefaultErrorAttributes which you could do it in your custom implementation too:

**Path:**

```
String path = getAttribute(requestAttributes, "javax.servlet.error.request_uri");
if (path != null) {
    errorAttributes.put("path", path);
}
```

**Timestamp:**

```
errorAttributes.put("timestamp", new Date());
```

The documentation on error customization in spring boot is [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-error-handling).

```
@Bean
public ErrorAttributes errorAttributes() {
    return new DefaultErrorAttributes() {
        @Override
        public Map<String, Object> getErrorAttributes(RequestAttributes requestAttributes, boolean includeStackTrace) {
            Map<String, Object> errorAttributes = super.getErrorAttributes(requestAttributes, includeStackTrace);
            // customize here
            return errorAttributes;
        }

   };
}
```

Or you could write a custom implementation:

```
@Component
public class CustomErrorAttributes extends DefaultErrorAttributes {

    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> getErrorAttributes(RequestAttributes requestAttributes, boolean includeStackTrace) {
        Map<String, Object> errorAttributes = super.getErrorAttributes(requestAttributes, includeStackTrace);
        // customize here
        return errorAttributes;
    }
}
```

The `ErrorAttributes` bean customizes the error response below:

```
{
   "timestamp": 1413883870237,
   "status": 500,
   "error": "Internal Server Error",
   "exception": "org.example.ServiceException",
   "message": "somthing goes wrong",
   "path": "/index"
}
```

The `"exception"` attribute can be customized using the `@ExceptionHandler`. A @`ControlerAdvice` could be used to customize the exception generically across controllers. To customize at the Controller level, you could place them within the controller.

**In your case:**

```
   @ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, reason="Invalid Inputs")
    @ExceptionHandler(CustomException.class)
    private void errorHanlder() {
        //Log exception
    }


  public Map<String, Object> getErrorAttributes(RequestAttributes requestAttributes, boolean includeStackTrace) {
    Map<String, Object> errorAttributes = super.getErrorAttributes(requestAttributes, includeStackTrace);
    Throwable error = getError(requestAttributes);
    if (error instanceof CustomException) {
        errorAttributes.put("errorList", ((CustomException)error).getErrors());
    }
    return errorAttributes;
}
```

Comment: I tried to integrate this function in my controller but I got this exception each time I made a call to my endpoint :
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "generic/error", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers

Comment: I think you are implementing the REST endpoint. So, use ResponseEntity.

Comment: This solution is what I talked about in the question post. I can use it but how can I get the path and timestamp attribute from the exception body so that I can add them to the custom error object please?

Comment: Sorry! I overlooked.Updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks @YuVi . The method errorAttributes should be declared in the controller class? And this declaration will add a new key value pair to all the exceptions or should I customize this in every exception handler seperatly ?

Comment: Anywhere, as long as your bean is registered in the context, you are good. It would takes precedence over DefaultErrorAttributes. This is your generic error response format and you should do it only in ONE place as long as your exception format is same. You could use @ControllerAdvice to define the ExceptionHandler for all the REST endpoints.

Comment: Thank you so much. I just integrated the CustomErrorAttributes and it works perfectly however, I don't understand how can we use this solution with @ControllerAdvice since this controller will handle exceptions and return a new different object.
Are errorAttributes will be added to the object defined in the responseEntity?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145918/discussion-between-habchi-and-yuvi).

Answer (score 6):

Previous answer really has it all there but somehow it took me a while to figure it out, so in summary basically the simplest way to accomplish this is to have a bean like this:

```
@Bean
public ErrorAttributes errorAttributes() {
    return new DefaultErrorAttributes() {
        @Override
        public Map<String, Object> getErrorAttributes(RequestAttributes requestAttributes,
                boolean includeStackTrace) {
            Map<String, Object> errorAttributes = super.getErrorAttributes(requestAttributes, includeStackTrace);
            Throwable error = getError(requestAttributes);
            if (error instanceof CustomExceptionthere) {
                errorAttributes.put("errorList", ((CustomException)error).getErrors());
            }
            return errorAttributes;
        }

    };
```