# Returning DTO from @RestControllerAdvice @ExceptionHandler method

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have the following `@ExceptionHandler` method in a `@RestControllerAdvice`:

```
 @ExceptionHandler(BusinessException.class)
 public ResponseEntity<Object> onException(BusinessException exception, WebRequest request) {

     Locale locale = request.getLocale();
     String message = messageSource.getMessage(exception.errorCode.toString(),
             exception.arguments, locale);

     ErrorDto errorDto = new ErrorDto(
             exception.errorCode,
             exception.arguments,
             message
     );

     return new ResponseEntity(errorDto, new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.CONFLICT);

}
```

And the `ErrorDto` is:

```
public class ErrorDto {

    ErrorCode errorCode;
    String[] arguments = new String[]{};
    String message;

    public ErrorDto(ErrorCode errorCode, String[] arguments, String message){

        this.errorCode = errorCode;
        this.arguments = arguments;
        this.message = message;

    }

}
```

But the response I get when a `BusinessException` is thrown is:

```
{
    "timestamp": 1500459833663,
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "exception": "com.ciet.app.exceptions.BusinessException",
    "message": "No message available",
    "path": "/CietApi/errorCodeTest"
}
```

Why don't I see the `ErrorDto` in the response?

Comment: Are you sure that the given ExceptionHandler is called when the exception occured. As per the response, It is handled by defult ExceptionHandler.

Comment: remove the WebRequest request parameter. and then try.

Comment: Yes I can debug and see the return statement inside the handler is called. Also if I return the exception itself instead of the DTO, I get the exception as the response. Removing WebRequest param does not help either. I need it to get the locale anyway.

Comment: Check if you have any other `@ControllerAdive`.

Comment: I don't. The problem was that the dto fields were not public. Interesting that the exception is handled by default handler without warnings.

Comment: Take a look at this thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44375456/add-new-field-in-body-exception-spring-rest).

Answer (score 1):

`ErrorDto` fields needed to be public or need to have public getters.